# Speaking partner

Tags: german-to-english, speaking

I Am self-studying Deutch my level is A2.1 but I do not practice speaking because I don't have anyone to speak with. I am looking for speaking partner preferably native or at the same level or higher we can use discord or any similar app.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not a contact forum

Comment: You may want to try e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/language_exchange/

Comment: @Janka thanks alot